# main: commad not found

Tags: git, bash

Взялся за написание сервиса автоматического пуша изменений моих записок в программе Obsidian через `systemd`.
Написал простой скрипт на bash:

```
#!bin/bash
PWD="/home/clipslemon/My_Git_lab/obsidian"

cd ${PWD}
RES=$(git status | grep -c "nothing to commit, working tree clean")
DATE=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
if [ ${RES} == 0 ]; then
    echo "Есть изменения в ветке гита."
    $(git add *)
    $(git commit -m "Автоматический коммит: ${DATE}")
    echo "Все изменения добавлены и закоментированы"
    $(git push origin)
    echo "Все изменения отправлены."
else
    echo "Изменений в ветке гита нет."
fi
```

Возникает при его исполнении следующая ошибка:

```
git.sh: line 10: [main: command not found
```

Единственное, что удалось выяснить, что main - это моя ветка в гите. Как дальше с этим работать не ясно.
Прочитал много информации на тему `$PATH` переменной, пробовал внутри скрипта и сам гит и сам скрипт через export добавлять в переменную, но не помогло.

Если я вызываю этот `.sh` скрипт вручную, то он несмотря на ошибку отрабатывает, если же ожидать его выполнения в `systemd`, то система зависает и не выполняется дальше этой строчки, выбрасывая ошибку.

Система: ubuntu 23.04

Comment: Зачем вы завернули все команды git в `$()`?

Comment: Видимо проблема была в этом. Использовал из-за ошибочного восприятия command substitute. Бегло ознакомившись с ним подумал, что это связано со всеми командами. Но сейчас не происходит push, виснет на нем. Буду дальше разбираться.

Comment: Переменные вроде надо вставлять не `${PWD}`, а просто `$PWD`.

Comment: @wchistow разницы нет

Comment: Для начала шебанг с ошибкой `#!bin/bash` надо `#!/bin/bash`